# How to return a variable object in kotlin function

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m newbie in kotlin development, and I need to return a String or an a List var in one function with Any, but I can't get the expected result:

```
fun loadEmployeesFromApi ():Any {
        var error = false
        var message = ""
        var sellersList:List<SellersItem> = emptyList()
        retrofit?.let {
            val service = it.create(ApiService::class.java)
            val call = service.listEmployeesData("getSellers")

            call.enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseSellers> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseSellers>, t: Throwable) {
                    error = true
                    message = "No se pudieron obtener los registros de vendedores debido a un problema de conexión al servidor"
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseSellers>, response: Response<ResponseSellers>) {
                    val code  = try {
                        response.body()!!.code!!.toInt()
                    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        0
                    }
                    when (code) {
                        200 -> {
                            /** response.body().sellers retorna una sellers: list<SellersItem> con los registros de los vendedores que pueden acceder a la app
                             **Datos que contiene el objeto:
                             ** usuario
                             * id
                             * nombre
                             * contrasenia
                             **/
                            sellersList = response.body()?.sellers as List<SellersItem>
                        } 0 -> {
                            error = true
                            message = "No se pudieron obtener los registros de vendedores, el servidor no retornó una respuesta"
                        } 404 -> {
                            error = true
                            message = "No hay registros de vendedores activos"
                        } else -> {
                            error = true
                            message = "Ocurrió un error al obtener los registros de vendedores, el servidor retornó $code de respuesta"
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        return if (error) {
            message
        } else {
            sellersList
        }
    }
```

when I see the logs in logCat of Android Studio for see what my function returns only show '[]', any sugestion for my noob problem?

Comment: I strongly recommend looking into `sealed classes` here. You can define a `sealed class Result`, and then two implementations `data class Success(val employees: List<SellersItem>) : Result()`, `data class Failure(val message: String) : Result()`. Then your method can return `Result` rather than `Any`. The consumers can then do an exhaustive `when` statement with smart-casts on the result: `when (result) { is Success -> println(result.employees); is Failure -> println(result.message) }`

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you are handling the return after doing an asynchronous call,
this causes the return to be made before you get the response - So neither the error or sellersList is ever getting set and its just returning an empty list. Instead of returning something directly you may want to consider passing in a success and error callback or a listener as a parameter and then give the result to the callback.

something like:

```
fun loadEmployeesFromApi (successCallback: (List<SellersItem>)->Unit, errorCallback: (String)->Unit) { 

     ...
```

and make the call when you load the data

```
when (code) {
    200 -> {
        /** response.body().sellers retorna una sellers: list<SellersItem> con los registros de los vendedores que pueden acceder a la app
        **Datos que contiene el objeto:
        ** usuario
        * id
        * nombre
        * contrasenia
        **/
        sellersList = response.body()?.sellers as List<SellersItem>
        successCallback(sellersList)
    } 0 -> {
        error = true
        message = "No se pudieron obtener los registros de vendedores, el servidor no retornó una respuesta"
        errorCallback(message)
    } 404 -> {
        error = true
        message = "No hay registros de vendedores activos"
        errorCallback(message)
    } else -> {
        error = true
        message = "Ocurrió un error al obtener los registros de vendedores, el servidor retornó $code de respuesta"
        errorCallback(message)
    }
}
```

and you can make the call like this:

```
loadEmployeesFromApi({ sellerList ->
    // handle success
}, { errorMessage ->
    // handle error
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a generic concept here.

pass T and handle accordingly

Comment: I don't think that's the case here, he is returning a string on failure and a list on success - the caller of the function wouldn't know to expect a failure when its making the call.